# Event 'Window load' not work in opera with prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, document, opera

I use prototype ver 1.6.0.2

```
Event.observer(window,'load',function(){
     function1();// function with ajax request
     function2();//another function with ajax request
});
```

It work on FireFox,Chrome but in Opera it work strange
Func2 and fucnc2 not runing but if page scroll down it runing both function immediately

Plz help.
Thanks.

Comment: Strange. Can you post a live link? What happens if you replace the function calls with a simple `alert("Hello");`?

Comment: I can't it on localhost Page in precessing load any tyme 5,10,20 min but when page screoled down all work.Any suggestion in this situation ?

Comment: Maby used js scroled down + scroled up page ?

Answer (score 1):

function is:

```
Event.observe(element, eventName, handler)
```

not:

```
Event.observer(element, eventName, handler)
```

@see: http://www.prototypejs.org/api/event/observe

(Opera is always right) :-)